# Automating creating receive location for BizTalk using Powershell when you can't see the error

Tags: powershell, automation, biztalk

I need Powershell to create receive port and location in an already existing application every time the script is ran.  The job of this receive location is to pick up a file every time a file is dropped in a folder location that exists on a file share of another server, which later a send port will be created to place the file somewhere else.  I have the below script that is located on the desktop of the server my BizTalk is on.  When I run it, there is an error that pops up on the screen.  I do not know what this error is, because it disappears immediately. The only thing that I know is the writing is red and that nothing has been created. I am not sure what is wrong with my current script. Because I cannot give out the file location and server location for security reasons, I have commented them out in this question.  The following script I have so far is below

```
#Create a receive port function#
#A new receive location will also be created and associated with the receive port#
#================================================================================#

Function CreateRPandRL()
{
    #Creating Receive Port
    $myReceivePort = $catalog.AddNewReceivePort($false)
    $myReceivePort.Name = "My Receive Port"

    #Creating Receive Location
    $myReceiveLocation = $myReceivePort.AddNewReceiveLocation()

    foreach ($handler in $catalog.ReceiveHandlers)
    {
        if ($handler.TransportType.Name -eq "File")
        {
            $myReceiveLocation.ReceiveHandler = $handler
            break
        }
    }

    #Associate a transport protocol and URI with receive location
    $myReceiveLocation.TransportType = $catalog.ProtocolTypes["File"]
    $myReceiveLocation.Address = #the file location that I am using which exists on another server

    #Assign the first receive pipeline found to process the message
    foreach ($pipeline in $catalog.Pipelines)
    {
        if ($pipeline.Type -eq [Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.PipelineType] "Receive")
        {
            $myReceiveLocation.ReceivePipeline = $pipeline
            break
        }

    #Enable the receive location
    $myReceiveLocation.Enable = $true
    }

    #Try to commit the changes made so far.  If the commit fails,
    #roll back changes
    $catalog.SaveChanges()
}

#================================================================================#
#Main Script#
#================================================================================#

#make sure the ExplorerOM assembly is loaded
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadwithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")

#Connect to the BizTalk management database
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER = #the BizTalk server location I am using; DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDB; Integrated Security=SSPI"

#Create the new receive port with its receive location
CreateRPandRL
```

Comment: Have you tried adding pause to the script so you can see the error?

Comment: Presuming that popping up error is PowerShell error in console, I suggest enable transcription, see
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7)
This should log all script inputs and outputs and then actual error should be clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Receive Location and Send Port in Existing BizTalk Application using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454499/create-receive-location-and-send-port-in-existing-biztalk-application-using-powe)